# Examples of non Noetherian rings satisfying ACC condition for annihilators

Tags: abstract-algebra, noetherian

I am reading Goddearl and Warfield book and I see that the common examples of Goldie rings are Noetherian semiprime rings. However I am wondering about rings that satisfy the ascending chain condition on annihilators which are not right Noetherian rings. Does anyone know some example?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Your question can be recommended to be closed due to its quality. To avoid this (and attracting downvotes), please also mention your understanding and try to solve the question. If possible, please also provide additional information on the topic/question. For more on how to ask a good question, you may refer: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Obviously any non-Noetherian domain works:

1. $\mathbb R[x_1,x_2,\ldots]$ in countably many variables.
2. $\mathbb Z + x\mathbb Q[x]\subseteq \mathbb Q[x]$ is another example that doesn't even have the ACC on principal ideals.
3. The ring of holomorphic functions on $\mathbb C$ is another example.

Here are some [rings which are not left Noetherian but have the ACC on left annihilators.](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=89l&L=64l) You may also find something different in some [rings which are not left Noetherian but have the ACC on right annihilators.](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=89r&L=64l)

If you were really wondering about non-right-Noetherian right-Goldie rings, then the three examples above still qualify. There are actually more hits for [non-right Noetherian, left Goldie rings](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=86r&L=64l), in particular $\mathbb Z\langle x,y\rangle/\langle y^2, yx\rangle$.